# default value of model.UUIDField() doesnt seem to be called in django graphene

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, graphene-python, graphene-django

I am trying to build an application with django and graphene and I want to set a default value for one of the fields in my model. The mutation is really straight forward. I've passed all the required arguments as objects and the optional ones with `**kwargs`.

Django's docs on `**options` for `models.UUIDField()` says that if None type object is sent to the model field, default value will be used.

When I try to use my mutation without passing any values/ passing None as a value to the argument, I get **graphql.error.located_error.GraphQLLocatedError: NOT NULL constraint failed: games_game.groupid** error is raised.

Here is a [pastebin](https://dpaste.org/bVhX) for Tracebacks, `models.py` and `schema.py` to my project.

Answer (score 0):

A developer from [django](https://webchat.freenode.net/#django) made me regular constructor rules apply on django models as well!

here is a simple fix to my problem for anyone in the future.

```
    groupid = kwargs.get('groupid', None)
    gid_extra = {'groupid': groupid} if groupid else {}
    game = Game(name=name, price=price, datereleased=datereleased, 
    description=description, **gid_extra)
    game.save()
```